# Checking the grammaticality "bound to make mistake"

Tags: grammaticality

Could you please tell me if there is an error in this sentence?

> Unless you are careful, you are bound to make mistake in your work.

The book offers:

> (a) Unless you are careful,
>   (b) you are bound to make mistake
>   (c) in your work.
>   (d) No error.

Comment: First, can you tell us what **you** think about it?

Comment: since i am begieer in eng lang i suppose bound should be replced with abound

Comment: Did the test guide where you found this give the answer? BTW, replacing _bound_ with _abound_ is NOT the right answer, but it's always good to present a theory when you ask a question like this. That accomplishes two things: (1) it lets us know you've put some thought into it, and (2) it helps the rest of the community more accurately diagnose where you might be confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in part (b). The sentence could be rewritten in one of two ways:

> Unless you are careful, you are bound to make **a** mistake in your work.

or:

> Unless you are careful, you are bound to make **mistakes** in your work.

But, in English, we don't say *make mistake*. We can *make mistakes*, or *make a mistake*, if we are making only one.

Comment: (opinion) The second option seems more natural to me, perhaps because *a* seems slightly too specific when talking about mistakes in general.

Comment: @snail - I'd concur with that opinion for the general case. There might be a few specific exceptions, though, such as a math teacher giving advice about how to do a proof.